# pandas - using a dataframe to find the mean by dropping duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, mean

I have a list of sales data which has a header which look like this:

```
Product ID  SN           Age    Gender  Item ID Item Name           Price
0   0   Lisim78       20    Male    108     Extraction,         3.53
1   1   Lisovynya38   40    Male    143     Frenzied Scimitar   1.56
2   2   Ithergue48    24    Male    92      Final Critic        4.88
3   3   Chamassasya86 24    Male    100     Blindscythe         3.27
4   4   Iskosia90     23    Male    131     Fury                1.44
```

There are obviously a number of sales items which are sold multiple times.  I'm trying to get the mean of the sales price.  Here's the code which I created

```
average_price = purchase_data_df.groupby('Item ID')[["Price"]].mean()
print(average_price)
```

But this seems to only give the mean across each Item ID.  How do I code to get the overall mean?

Comment: just remove the groupby:
`average_price = purchase_data_df[["Price"]].mean()`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have items which appear multiple times in the sales data.  Simply removing the groupby will give me the mean with those items which have sold multiple times added weight to the calculation.  i.e. if Item A has sold 3 times, Item B sold twice, and item C once, that would calculate (3A + 2B + C) / 6 instead of (A + B + C) / 3 wouldn't it?

Comment: `df[['Item Name', 'Price']].drop_duplicates().mean()`

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!